# How to Scroll faster while holding control key in macOS?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, big-sur, karabiner

In macOS, how to Scroll faster while holding the control key. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you holding the Control key?

Comment: Also, is there one app you want to scroll faster?

Comment: This sounds more like you need a different mouse or trackpad. Logitech offers good mice

Answer (score 1):

You can use the scroll bar to advance faster than a page at a time. The scroll bar can be set so your document jumps to wherever you place the cursor. If you click in the cursor bar the slider will immediately go to that point in the document. Much faster than going page by page. To set this go to System Preferences, General, and about halfway down that pane is the option to Jump to the spot that's clicked.